# Why does badges/ids/recipients return badges not users?

Tags: support, api-v2, badges

I can't understand why badges/{ids}/recipients returns badges and not users? You must pass the badge ID in, so it should be given that you already know what the badge is. If it returns 30 objects you get 30 copies of the badge data. That doesn't sound very efficient, especially given that a lot of changes in v2.0 have been about making things more efficient.

Surely it would be better just to return user objects?
If a copy of the badge must be returned then add a field called "context" as a sibling (at the same level) as "items"?

Answer (score 1):

Remember the existence of [/badges/recipients](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/badge-recipients), which does not take any badge ids.  For that method, simply returning users would be essentially useless; /badges/{ids}/recipients returns the same type in-keeping with the `/something/{ids}/tail` pattern.

Also note that if you pass multiple badge ids you need the badge data to distinguish who earned which badge in the returns.

Filters allow you to turn the `*/recipients` methods into "just users" methods: [users who recently received Teacher on Stack Overflow for example](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/badge-recipients-by-ids#ids=1&filter=!6PCctzjw2WX4o&site=stackoverflow&run=true).

Comment: Oh right I didn't remember that one. Why not make badge.user, into badge.users? That way only one copy of each badge is returned?